# How do you split a rosbag into several files without calling rosbag filter multiple times?

Tags: ros

I want to split a 100-GB rosbag into 100 1-GB bags.  I tried using rosbag filter but it takes a long time as I have to run each filter manually and each time, it performs a scan of the full bag.  Is there a better way to perform this split (either through command line or Python script)?

Answer (score 6):

You could simply use a function like this to split your bag file into chunks:

```py
import rosbag

def extract_chunks(file_in, chunks):
    bagfile = rosbag.Bag(file_in)
    messages = bagfile.get_message_count()
    m_per_chunk = int(round(float(messages) / float(chunks)))
    chunk = 0
    m = 0
    outbag = rosbag.Bag("chunk_%04d.bag" % chunk, 'w')
    for topic, msg, t in bagfile.read_messages():
        m += 1
        if m % m_per_chunk == 0:
            outbag.close()
            chunk += 1
            outbag = rosbag.Bag("chunk_%04d.bag" % chunk, 'w')
        outbag.write(topic, msg, t)
    outbag.close()
```

Be aware, that this method uses the number of messages to perform splitting, hence the resulting chunk bag files do not necessarily have the same size.